# How to exclude .lib file from linker command line argument in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker

I am compiling a vc++ program which is showing below error
`error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\credentialproviders\Win32\Debug\Helpers.lib'`

how i can remove that `Helpers.lib` file reference from linker command line argument because in **project settings->linker->commandline** its in `readonly` mode and I can't edit this to remove that line. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

thanks

Comment: If you're sure that removing it is the right move, you can do so through Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

Comment: its not there, i searched there but no lib with that name exists.

Comment: It must be there. Try different configuration (Debug/Release)

Comment: it shouldn't be there, at least two another way to link exists, looks at my reply below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this lib is not referenced in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, so check Project Dependencies, and remove any dependency on porject Helpers. also it's possible that this linking is done from code by `#pragma comment(lib, "Helpers)`

Answer (score 2):

Search the .vcproj file, and the project source code for "Helpers.lib". There are a couple places it can get linked in, and this is the simplest way to find it.

Otherwise, look for:

1. Project properties -> linker -> inputs
2. In the solution explorer, see if the .lib is included anywhere in the project tree.
3. Anywhere in the source code, `#pragma comment(lib, "helpers.lib")`
4. If Helpers is a project in your solution, check project dependencies for the project. By default, thisk linking is done implicitly if the project depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think the above answers it properly. I just had this same problem and the way to fix it is to go to View->Property Manager. double click `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` and go to Linker->Input. There you can edit out the additional dependencies that were previously read only. Do it for both debug/release versions if needed.