# Visual Studio 2010: Linker > Command Line contains unneeded .lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

Similar problem to this: [How to exclude .lib file from linker command line argument in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569653/how-to-exclude-lib-file-from-linker-command-line-argument-in-vc)

Basically I was doing a school assignment that requires my c++ program to call my oracle database. I was messing around with Oracle OCCI and set the libraries **"oraocci11.lib" "oraocci11d.lib"** to be included to all projects by default.

I followed the settings that is explained [here](http://thisthread.blogspot.com/2011/07/oracle-occi-for-visual-studio-2010.html)

After which I tried to compile a sample project from the same source to test the OCCI and got an error like this:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class
oracle::occi::Environment * __cdecl oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(enum
oracle::occi::Environment::Mode,void *,void * (__cdecl*)(void *,unsigned int),void 
*     (__cdecl*)(void *,void *,unsigned int),void (__cdecl*)(void *,void *))"
(?createEnvironment@Environment@occi@oracle@@SAPAV123@W4Mode@123@PAXP6APAX1I@ZP6APAX11I@ZP6AX11@Z@Z)
referenced in function _main
```

My default Linker > Command Line

```
/OUT:"C:\Users\Jem\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\sql\Debug\sql.exe"
/INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO "msvcprtd.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib"
"winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" 
"uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "oraocci11.lib" "oraocci11d.lib" /MANIFEST 
/ManifestFile:"Debug\sql.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION 
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Jem\Documents
\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\sql\Debug\sql.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /PGD:"C:\Users
\Jem\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\sql\Debug\sql.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE 
/NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

If you look at the above properties there this two libraries being included "oraocci11.lib" "oraocci11d.lib"

I would like to remove those two off the Command Line but the option is in Read-Only.

After being frustrated over the OCCI, I tried to 
 make a simple program call main.cpp with just "int main() { return 0; }" inside.
I build it and I get this

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'oraocci11.lib'
```

I included the folders containing the libraries.
This time, I get this

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprtd.lib'
```

I have tried in my notebook and it worked fine. My notebook VS2010 is a fresh install of VS2010.

So I figured it might be the command line since I have already excluded all the folders and libraries in the properties before I attempt to build with the first setting that returns the oraocci11.lib error.

I have done all the possible solutions I have found online to no avail.
I have tried to undo all the settings already (Directories and Additional Dependencies)
Even installing and reinstalling my VS2010 wasn't helping.
Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Edit your question to include a copy and paste of it.

Comment: `and set the libraries to be included to all projects by default`.  That's where it comes from, presumably.  You didn't describe what you did.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem. I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the solution for me was to go Project properties->Common Properties and remove the references to the unwanted libraries. That got rid of the command line entries to the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You must not link release and debug libraries at the same time: e.g. `oraocci11d.lib` is the debug version; `oraocci11.lib` the release version. It will confuse the linker (due to the same symbols being available in both versions, while it won't be able to determine which one you want). Also, I wouldn't add such libraries to the standard libraries to be linked against (as it might slow down linking).

Comment: I only noticed that after I failed to compile. After I tried to undo all the settings, and only including the oraocci11d.lib, I still fail to get the program running.
The problem I'm facing now is that I can't even run simple programs without getting the above linker errors.

Comment: Revert all your changes, don't even include that one lib and see what happens (using a new/blank project).

Comment: I have reverted all changes, removed both libaries from the dependencies already. Those two libraries are "stuck" in the Linker > Command Line (as shown above) to the properties and I can't seems to find a way to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which worked for me so far.

At least my `VS2010` is working and compiling my previous projects.

I just messed around with the Property Sheet on my computer.

```
C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0
```

Just copy and replace `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props` inside the folder to the `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props`

Thanks for all the input though